# Inserting a v-model into a vuejs element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do something like this, do not know how to describe in technical term, can't seem to find a solution for this.

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="model1" />
</div>

<div>
  <div id="model2">ABCDEFG</div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {'model1': 'value'},
...
...
...
});
</script>
```

How can i add model2 element into my #app data? I do not want to wrap my model2 inside of #app because it is a partial, and is shared throughout the application. Is there a way i can inject it on a particular page when it is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that `model2` div a separate component o that it can be reused anywhere you want like this:

**html**

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="model1" />
   <reusable-comp></reusable-comp>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>

var reusableComp = {
    template: `
        <div id="model2">
          <div>ABCDEFG</div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
    `,
    data(){
        return{
           //reactive properties for this component 
        }
    }
}


new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {'model1': 'value'},
        components:{
            reusableComp
        }
...
...
...
});
</script>
```

You can also register that as a global component like this

```
Vue,.component('reusableComp',{ //...options })`
```

See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-Components) for more on components